# How to make a web app running on a local server secure?

Tags: django, ssl, server, https, lets-encrypt

I wish to create an app using Django, which users can use on their respective local networks. I want to make this secure, and I have trouble finding a way. Most answers point to using self-signed certificates on the server followed by installing certificates on each individual device on the network. However, this might be complicated and too much effort for the users, who may not be so tech savvy.

Is there a simpler, cleaner way of making this app secure within the local network? Something I can automate as well.

Comment: certificate without certificate authority has poor level of security. You can create your own CA for local network, and local services. But still you need to add this CA to client's computers(I think). I have found this link: https://superuser.com/questions/630914/can-i-be-a-root-certificate-authority-for-my-local-network

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run django on https, you can use this package [sslserver](https://pypi.org/project/django-sslserver/)

However, as the certificate is self generated, browser will show security warnings.

Comment: I don't think it is maintained anymore. The last github commit was almost 4 years ago. Thank you!